# Filter the results based on substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a  table

```
BookNName,Col1
```

Col1(nvarchar) has data in the following format

```
BookNo|ShelfNo|BookQty
```

```
Col1
-----

1|1|763
2|2|989
3|3|431
4|4|
```

I have to  display only the BookQty and also add a condition that BookQty<900

So, my output should be

```
BookName BookQty
ABC        763
XYZ        431
WEST            <----------Should dislpay blank value also
```

***What I tried***

To display only BookQty, I wrote the following -

```
select BookName, case when charindex('|',Col1,1)>=2 then right(Col1, charindex('|', reverse(col1))-1)
else ''
end
as 'BookQty'
```

This is giving output as

```
BookName BookQty
ABC        763
SOUTH      989
XYZ        431
WEST
```

Now, I have to add the condition that BookQty<900

For that I tried -

```
select BookName, case when charindex('|',Col1,1)>=2 then right(Col1, charindex('|', reverse(col1))-1)
else ''
end
as 'BookQty'
from Table1
where right(Col1, charindex('|', reverse(col1))-1)<'900'
```

This is giving me error

> Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function

I know this is due to the blanks in the column. But is there any other way to do this. I cannot change the database values.

Comment: `Col1` contains data like `1|1|763`? So you have delimited data in your table? That's the real problem. Fix your design.

Comment: @ThomA Unfortunately I don't have access and authority to fix the design.

Comment: As for the error, that's because you don't handle values missing a pipe (`|`) in your `WHERE`. `right(Col1, charindex('|', reverse(col1))-1)` resolves to `-1` when there is no pipe, and you can't have the -1 right most characters.

Comment: @ThomA yes I know the error is due to null value. That is why wondering if there is any other way to achieve the desired results.

Comment: Your "solution" will fail even if you fix the LEFT problem, because '92' will not be < '900' due to varchars. All thanks to the bad design of the original table.

Comment: Have you considered a cross apply with `STRING_SPLIT()`?

Comment: Good point on the `varchar` to `varchar` comparison, @siggemannen . Keep banging the "fix your design" drum. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real solution is to **fix your design**. Storing delimited data in your database is *bad design*, and the problems it causes are many; that you've encountered one today just tells you further to *fix your design*. If you can't, then get whoever can to fix it, it *needs* fixing.

As for the problem, you have values without pipes (`|`); your bad data is inconsistent. Really you should be using `NULL`, not blank strings (surprise, this error wouldn't occur then either, like if you had a good design). You can, however, check the returned value of `CHARINDEX` and `NULL` it if there isn't a pipe (the returned value is `0`):

```sql
SELECT T1.BookName,
       RIGHT(T1.Col1, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', REVERSE(T1.Col1)), 0) - 1) AS BookQty --Don't use literal strings for aliases, they're for literal strings; they have "gotchas" and some syntaxes are deprecated
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int,RIGHT(T1.Col1, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|', REVERSE(T1.Col1)), 0) - 1)) < '900'; --As it's a string, then try to convert it. We don't want values like "six" or "1K".
```